Change set error validating the flow definition component
First of all I have 2 errors.
1.Error validating the changeset.
-I have a flow I created but I'm getting this error message in changeset:
"insufficient access rights on cross-reference id"
So I remove everything leaving only one 1 decision element and no condition in start. I am logged as System Administrator and I make sure that all the object in my profile is check. I have a System Administrator in change set as well. But why despite having almost no logic in my flow I still got this error validating the changeset?




Error opening the flow. The flow just got deployed successfully using changeset and I'm about to activate it. I am having a hard time fixing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.


FLow advance properties


show a screen shot of the flow's advanced properties; check the flow version to verify it is v60

Hello, it is running in v56. But I had a flow that got deployed and activated as well with v56.

Also I tried updating the version to 60 but I can't sill open the flow.. "We can't open this flow right now. Please try again. Error ID: 562749744"

a couple of thoughts -- 1) try rebuilding the basic flow all over again under a new name - then deploy; 2) what is the Object of the record-triggered flow? Is it available to you in the PROD org?

yes.. I'm just deploying to another sandbox though. Still I need to know the cause of the issue.

sorry, I thought this was a sandbox->PROD deploy; if sandbox->sandbox; for the target object in question, is that object enabled in the target sandbox (feature enablement).  For example, if deploying Swarm, the target org needs Swarm enabled and the running user needs permissions for that object
